# Install Chrome/Cromium on Amazon Linux v2 (ARM64/aarch64/Gravitone)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Does anyone know a working solution to install Google Chrome(Chromium) on Amazon Linux 2 with ARM64 architecture (Gravitone c6g.xlarge instance)? I need to run it in headless mode.
At the moment I can't find any packages in yum:

> No package **chromium** available.

When I try to install it using the RPM package I get the error:

> Error: Package: chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64 (/chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64)
> Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64 (/chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64)
> Requires: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.9)(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64 (/chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64)
> Requires: chromium-common(aarch-64) = 87.0.4280.141-1.el8
>
> Error: Package: chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64 (/chromium-87.0.4280.141-1.el8.aarch64)
> Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)

When I try to run **sudo yum install glibc** I get:

> glibc-2.26-39.amzn2.aarch64

Looks like Amazon Linux has installed own older version of glibc. Same situation with zlib package, available older version:

> zlib-1.2.7-18.amzn2.aarch64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To really solve the problem if you are using EC2 instance or any other server where you are running Amazon linux, you should follow the below steps .

Enable and install Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux by running the command

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

Post installing all the extra packages successfully, Install chromimum as usual

```
sudo yum install -y chromium
```

Once you do that Chromium will have all required such as libatk* libgdk* etc ...

You should be able to easily launch Chromium

The missed out packages that you are looking here, are actually not missedout they are kind of default you just have to enable them , this is well documented in AWS documentation .

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Comment: Thanks for your reaction but I asked about "Amazon Linux v2".

Comment: @BogdanPisarenko I have tested this in Amazon Linux V2 only , I never user version 1

Comment: Very interesting! What architecture did you use on? It was ARM64 in my case. I tried to install an  EPEL package. But it didn't contain chromium.

Comment: @BogdanPisarenko, did you ran ```sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y``` and then tried ```sudo yum install -y chromium``` . look properly for the command yum  install epel -y will not do the job for you

Comment: The current EPEL el7 repo does not contain chromium for aarch64

Comment: @aredridel Thanks for the confirmation of my supposing.

Comment: This works for me in Amazon Linux 2, but I had to use t2.medium capacity instead of the free tier t2.micro or t2.small. otherwise, redeploying my app using `eb deploy` would error out (i think due to running out of memory)

Comment: @kimbaudi t2 is not Graviton based - the whole problem is that Chromium does not have an ARM64 binary available.

Comment: There is no chromium package at all for Amazon Linux  2